# How to align itemized bullets in multicols environment with tcbox around one item

Tags: itemize, tcolorbox, multicol

Is there a way to render invisible the vertical space that the frame of a `\tcbox` takes up for the purposes of spacing bullets inside of the `multicols` environment?

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{lorem ipsum}
  \item{lorem ipsum}
  \item{lorem ipsum}
  \item{lorem ipsum}
  \item{lorem ipsum}
  \item{\tcbox[size=small,box align=base]{lorem ipsum}}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

produces this result where the second and fifth bullet points are not vertically aligned, and there is more vertical space between the text of the fifth and sixth bullet points than there is between the text of the second and third bullet points

[image: Misaligned bullets inside multicols environment]

I'd like the second and fifth bullet points to be vertically aligned, and I'd like an equal amount of space between the text of the fifth and sixth bullet points, ignoring the `\tcbox`.

Just `\smash`ing the `\tcbox` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You could try to wrap the whole itemize as a `tcbitemize` with equal heights for all boxes, hidding the drawn box for all but the last one, letting `tcolorbox` calculate the correct height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to put all the `\item`s without a box in a blank `\tcbox`. But still using the standard `itemize` environment. It is easier if you predefine the boxes beforehand like such

```
\newtcbox{\bbox}{blank,size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter,left=-1.3mm} % blank box
\newtcbox{\mybox}{size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter}
```

This creates a blank box called `\bbox` and the box you want visible called `\mybox`. Doing it beforehand ensures you make both boxes the same in terms of size etc. Note that for the blank box I've also added `left=-1.3mm`. This reduces the spacing on the left hand side so that the text in the blank boxes align horizontally with the leftmost edge of the visible box (this is what you had in your MWE). I got these values from the predefined values of the `small` box (see section 4.7.5, page 44 of the `tcolorbox` documentation). In particular, `boxsep=1.0mm` and `boxrule=0.3mm`. Hence, `-1.3mm` is perfect in this case to adjust the horizontal alignment of the text. Alternatively, you can leave this out and the text in the blank boxes will be horizontally aligned to the text in the visible box, which is also quite nice I think.

**MWE**

Note the addition of `skins` to `\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}`. This is required to get the `blank` box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newtcbox{\bbox}{blank,size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter,left=-1.3mm}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \mybox{lorem ipsum}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to reduce the amount of vertical space between the bullet points, then use `before skip=⟨glue⟩`. For example, here I've used `before skip=-2.5mm`.

**Reducing vertical space between bullet points MWE**

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newtcbox{\bbox}{blank,size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter,left=-1.3mm,before skip=-2.5mm}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{size=small,box align=base,nobeforeafter,before skip=-2.5mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \bbox{lorem ipsum}
  \item \mybox{lorem ipsum}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\item` does not have a mandatory argument, so `\item{...}` is 'wrong'

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Had just copied what the OP had written. I will edit the post.

Comment: +1 Thanks. This works, but it does increase the amount of vertical space that every bullet point takes up, which I'd like to avoid. (This is for a research poster, so space is precious.) So I might wait for other possible solutions before accepting.

Comment: @adam-liter You can adjust the amount of vertical space that every bullet point takes up by using before `skip=⟨glue⟩`. I've added this to my answer and shown an example. You can reduce the space as much as you want while still preserving the alignment of the bullet points.